# 12 digits format - is this a datetime or?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, types

I am working on a SQL server database and I have two columns in a table with values like these below.
I've tried converting to datetime, date, epoch, excel format, nothing seems to work, I can't find exactly what it is.
Maybe I am wrong and is not datetime?
What could it be?

```
428964571475
426594519082    
426594519086    
426594519091    
426594519095    
426594519097    
428964564747    
426594519102
```

Comment: The users here know far less about your database than you do. If you don't know what a random integer value represents some strangers from the internet have even less of a chance. You need to speak to whomever designed your database or the application that inserts the values into said database to find out what they represent. Documentation will help you too.

Comment: Maybe there is a hint in the name of the column? But no one else knows your database, what it models, the processes that feed this column, nor how this information is used.

Comment: The columns are named by one letter, the first one has the name 't', I know the rest of the columns - ids and names, but can't figure out the format of these two. It should be a datetime but I don't know how to convert it...

Comment: This could be a million different things, find out what is creating the data, then go and punch the person who thought naming a column `t` was a good idea.

Comment: The other commenters are correct.  There is no way of knowing.  Ultimately you need to contact the person who generated these values.  My intuition is that it is the date, including fractional part of day, multiplied by 10 million.  But what is the zero date?  30-Dec-1899? 01-Jan-1900? If so why are all the times near 11 AM? Try something like: declare @x bigint = 428964571475

select cast ( @x * 0.0000001 as datetime )

-- 2017-06-12 10:58:17.543

Comment: All we can do is guess, maybe it's the number of milliseconds since 1st January 2005. Maybe it's the number of milliseconds until the year 2033. Maybe it's the birthday of the dog of the person who wrote this. Maybe it's not a date and it's a random number. Or maybe they are phone numbers for Czechoslovakia.

Comment: Please try running new Date(426594519082) and the other values in your browser console. The output is a date from the 80s. Do these seem like something intuitive in the database you are working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@David Dubois thank you so much!!! that's the answer! So I was right, it's datetime, I couldn't figure out how to convert it, you saved me!

```
declare @x bigint = 428964571475 
select cast ( @x * 0.0000001 as datetime )
```